# Read and set Group Policy settings from C++ program

Tags: c++, active-directory, winapi, group-policy

I have a standalone Windows-NT based machine (not connected to any network) and I want to be able to read and later set the Group Policy settings via a C++ program.

Here's what I would do manually. Run gpedit.msc as administrator, then say I want to prevent users from accessing registry. So in the `"Local Group Policy Editor"` I'll go to

> User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> "Prevent access to registry editing tools"

and set it to `Enabled`.

Is there any way to do the same from a C++ program? Any code samples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Group Policy API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374177%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I found it myself while waiting... but they are so confusing. Any idea how to actually code what I want?

Comment: No. Personally I would do it from PowerShell or vbscript if you are stuck on xp.

Comment: OK then, any way to do it with WMI?